# Canonical construction of basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ from single vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Start with $\mathbb{R}^n$. If I take a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of norm $1$, it is not difficult to construct an explicit basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the form $B_v = (v, v_2, \cdots, v_n) \in SO(n)$. If I consider the map $B : v \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \to B_v \in SO(n)$, then the map $B$ cannot be continuous on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, put can be continuous on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ minus a north pole. An explicit construction is to take the $n-1$ partial derivatives of the stereographic projection (that gives a basis of the tangent plane of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ at $v$).

My question is: what about $\mathbb{C}^n$? Is there a "canonical (and smooth) way" to complete a vector $z \in \mathbb{C}^n$ with $\| z \| = 1$ into a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Thanks

Comment: Is the $n-1$ partial derivative really give you vector with length one?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your statement is not correct.

For some $n$, namely $n=2,4,8$ such a map exists : it is given by a (orthonormal) *trivialisation of the tangent bundle* of the sphere $S_{n-1}$.

For instance in dimension 2, it is given by $\nu(u)=iu$ where $i^2=-1$ after identifying $\bf R^2$ with $\bf C$. In dimension 4, after identifiying $\bf R^4$ with the quaternions the matrix of the right  multiplication by $q$ is orthogonal $q,Iq,Jq,Kq$. This is a deep theorem that the tangent bundle of the sphere $S_{n-1}$ is trivial only in dimension $2,4,8$ (for 8 use octonions).(Bott-Milnor-Kervaire)

Now your question reduces to understand if a certain complex bundle over $S^{2n-1}$ is trivial or not. At a point $p$ on the sphere, this bundle is the vectors orthogonal to $p$ in the hermitian sense, and the triviality implies also the triviality of the tangent bundle of the sphere (add the direction $ip$).

In other words, the existence of such a map implies  $2n-1= 1,3,7$, and $n=1,2,4$, and one can construct the map $\nu$ with the same argument (use quaternions, octonions).

Comment: But the OP is referring to $\mathbb S^{n}\setminus \{N\}$, and I think any bundle on such space is trivial?

Comment: @JohnMa : indeed, then the answer is obvious, and by the same argument.

Comment: I am not sure if it is obvious, the OP asks for a "canonical" one.

Comment: As you notice, the complex bundle on $S^n \setminus N$ made of tangent vectors orthogonal to the base point is trivial.

Comment: @Thomas, I understand that the theory says "yes, it is possible". Now, I really want to construct such a basis... and I could not do it straightforwardly. You say it is obvious, but I don't get why.

Comment: If you use the stereographic projection, you will check that the image of the complex vector bundle orthogonal to the the point in the hermitian sense is the kernel of the contact form $dz_n- 1/2\sum _{i=1}^{n-1}x_idy_i-y_idx_i$. As a (complex) base of this (contact form on $\bf R^{2n-1}$ you can take the vector fields $\partial_i- 1/2y_i\partial _n$.